# Jquery animate scrolltop not working in Chrome on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, scroll

I have a button to scroll to the top of the page. This is the jquery:

```
$("#scroll-top").unbind().on("click", function () {
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
})
```

But it doesn't work on my iPhone in Chrome. It works in Safari and it works on Chrome on my desktop. I tried using the ID of the body tag instead ($("#page), ) but it still doesn't work.

I don't know if window.scrollTo would work, but I don't want to use that regardless because I want a smooth animation.